# VB.NET TCPClient/Server Issue- Sending on a Timer

Tags: vb.net, timer, tcpclient, tcplistener

So my program starts out by counting how many processes of "XProcess" and has a timer to check every 1 second, which works great! I have the input of the count going into Setting variable. I then have a sub routine that takes that Setting variable, along with a IF statement to output that the TCPClient is sending the string ("One Process").

Well the issue is, I have no event to use with the sub routine and so I tied it in with the timer to send the message out every 1 second. The TCPClient sends it to a local address(127.0.0.1) right now, and sends it to a Textbox. Well PROBLEM!!!

It repeats ("One Process") over and over and over, which I can see why this happens.

**So with the Code below, how can the TCPClient send an notification of how many processes of "XProcess" to the TCPServer and the TCPSERVER to spit out that 1 or more processes are running ?** (with out the SERVER repeating the string (integer works as wel) over and over again)

The below works, but repeats how many processes are running as a string.

MainWindow.xaml.vb

```
Imports System.Windows.Threading
Imports System.Net.Sockets

Public Class MainWindow
    Private Run_ProgramRunCheck_timer As New DispatcherTimer
    Private Run_RecieveCheck_timer As New DispatcherTimer
    Dim processCount As Integer
    Private Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
        ServerStart()

        'Check for program changes every second

        ' Set interval for timer
        Run_ProgramRunCheck_timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)


        'Start timer on button click
        Run_ProgramRunCheck_timer.Start()

        AddHandler Run_ProgramRunCheck_timer.Tick, AddressOf __ProgramCheck


        'Check for Message Recieve every second

        ' Set interval for timer
        Run_RecieveCheck_timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)


        'Start timer on button click
        Run_RecieveCheck_timer.Start()

        AddHandler Run_RecieveCheck_timer.Tick, AddressOf _RecieveMessageConvert
        TCPClientSender()


    End Sub
    Public Sub __ProgramCheck()
        'This sub will be checked every 1 seconds for changes

        'Count number of processes
        processCount = Process.GetProcessesByName("tvnviewer").Count()
        My.Settings.TotalProcesses = processCount


    End Sub

    Public Sub TCPClientSender()
        My.Settings.TotalProcesses = 0
        If My.Settings.TotalProcesses = 1 Then
            Dim port As Int32 = 50000
            Dim client As New TcpClient("127.0.0.1", port)
            ' Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.


            Dim data As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("One Process")

            ' Get a client stream for reading and writing. 
            '  Stream stream = client.GetStream(); 
            Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()

            ' Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
        End If



    End Sub

    Public Sub _RecieveMessageConvert()

        TextBlock1.Text = My.Settings.StoreSentMessage
    End Sub
End Class
```

TCPServer.vb

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.IO

Public Module TCPServer

    Dim Server = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 50000) ' <-- Listen on Port 50,000
    Dim Client As New TcpClient
    Private ServerThread As Thread = Nothing
    Dim Message As String = ""
    Private Threads As New List(Of Thread)

    Public Sub ServerStart()
        ServerThread = New Thread(AddressOf ConnectionListener)
        ServerThread.IsBackground = True
        ServerThread.Start()
    End Sub
    Private Sub ConnectionListener()
        Try
            Server.Start()

            While True

                Dim client As TcpClient = Server.AcceptTcpClient ' Blocks until Connection Request is Received



                Dim Reader As New StreamReader(client.GetStream())

                While Reader.Peek > -1
                    Message = Message + Convert.ToChar(Reader.Read()).ToString


                End While


                My.Settings.StoreSentMessage = Message



            End While
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub




End Module
```

Comment: NOTE: "XPROCESS" means any process. Yes I have tvnviewer as the process, but the process name doesn't matter.

Comment: Your code is a bit messy and your indications are not too clear. Can you please explain what are the two timers expected to be doing? You are starting a first timer (populating .TotalProcesses), then you execute more code and call another timer (populating TextBlock1.Text). Both timers keep, presumably, running (once per second) as far as there is not a .Stop() method anywhere (although, logically, without performing the aforementioned intermediate actions). Can you please elaborate a bit more about what you want exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont you just want to do this:

```
Dim data As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(My.Settings.TotalProcesses)
```

I dont know how you ever get it to say "One Process" when you set the value to zero and then check if the value is 1 on the next line???

```
My.Settings.TotalProcesses = 0
If My.Settings.TotalProcesses = 1 Then
```